# Why setStyleSheet works strangely in different places in the code?

Tags: qt, qt5

I found that my styles for the child widget weren't working. Code:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    this->setStyleSheet("* { background-color: white; }");

    QVBoxLayout* vLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
    for(int i = 0; i < 30; ++i) {
        QPushButton * btn = new QPushButton(tr("word %1").arg(i));
        btn->setStyleSheet("background-color: gray;");
        vLayout->addWidget(btn);
    }
    QWidget* widget= new QWidget;
    widget->setLayout(vLayout);

    QScrollArea* techScroll = new QScrollArea();
    techScroll->setParent(this);
    techScroll->setStyleSheet("QScrollArea { border: none; background-color: transparent; }"
                          "QScrollBar:vertical {  border: none; background-color: transparent; width: 5px;}"
                          "QScrollBar::horizontal { border: none; background-color: transparent; height: 5px; }"
                          "QScrollBar::add-line, QScrollBar::sub-line { border: none; width: 0px; height: 0px; }"
                          "QScrollBar::add-page, QScrollBar::sub-page { background-color: transparent; }"
                          "QScrollBar::handle { background-color: #C4C4C4; border-radius: 2px; }"
    );
    techScroll->setWidgetResizable(true);
    techScroll->setWidget(widget);
    techScroll->move(50, 50);
    techScroll->setFixedWidth(300);
    techScroll->setFixedHeight(400);
}
```

[image]

It turned out that you need to write setParent function after pasting styles of child widget. Code:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    this->setStyleSheet("* { background-color: white; }");

    QVBoxLayout* vLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
    for(int i = 0; i < 30; ++i) {
        QPushButton * btn = new QPushButton(tr("word %1").arg(i));
        btn->setStyleSheet("background-color: gray;");
        vLayout->addWidget(btn);
    }
    QWidget* widget= new QWidget;
    widget->setLayout(vLayout);

    QScrollArea* techScroll = new QScrollArea();
    techScroll->setStyleSheet("QScrollArea { border: none; background-color: transparent; }"
                          "QScrollBar:vertical {  border: none; background-color: transparent; width: 5px;}"
                          "QScrollBar::horizontal { border: none; background-color: transparent; height: 5px; }"
                          "QScrollBar::add-line, QScrollBar::sub-line { border: none; width: 0px; height: 0px; }"
                          "QScrollBar::add-page, QScrollBar::sub-page { background-color: transparent; }"
                          "QScrollBar::handle { background-color: #C4C4C4; border-radius: 2px; }"
    );
    techScroll->setParent(this); // moved here
    techScroll->setWidgetResizable(true);
    techScroll->setWidget(widget);
    techScroll->move(50, 50);
    techScroll->setFixedWidth(300);
    techScroll->setFixedHeight(400);
}
```

[image]

Is this a bug or is this design and i'm not understanding something?

Qt version 5.15.2

Comment: I guess this has to do something with the fact, the the main window should have only one central widget and it is supposed to be set with `QMainWindow::setCentralWidget()`.

Comment: If I insert techScroll into QMainWindow::setCentralWidget() the problem remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

Probably It is intended to work like that. Like any `QWidget`,  `QScrollArea` snaps to the parent widget, so either you set the parent widget or you just pass `this` as input parameter, like:

```
new QScrollArea(this);
```

The issue may be due to the fact that stylesheet rendering is tricky.

Anyway, I can't stress this enough: rather use the ui designer than writing manually your ui code.

Comment: I am passing the parent object to the child object through the setParent function. I would have no questions if "new QScrollArea(this)" worked.